# Insertar un array en un array bidimensional

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando con el servicio de AFIP de facturacion electronica. Ynecesito operar con las alicuotas de 10,5%, 21%, y 27%.
Pero el caso es que si en la factura no hay productos con 10,5% por ejemplo, no se debe informar dicha alicuota.El array de cada impuesto tiene esta forma:

```
    array( 'Id' => $regfeiva10['id'], 
          'BaseImp' => $regfeiva10['baseimp'], 
          'Importe' => $regfeiva10['importe'] );
```

Entonces necesito concatenar los arrays que sean necesarios segun los productos tengan un 10 0 u 21 % de impuestos, etc..

Probe lo siguiente (array_push())pero no me concatena nada

```
 if ($regfeiva10["importe"]>0){
       $regfeiva= array( 'Id' => $regfeiva10['id'], 
                                'BaseImp' => $regfeiva10['baseimp'], 
                                'Importe' => $regfeiva10['importe'] );
   }
   if ($regfeiva21["importe"]>0){
     if ($regfeiva!=null){
         array_push($regfeiva, array ( 'Id' => $regfeiva21['id'], 
                                'BaseImp' => $regfeiva21['importe'], 
                                'Importe' => $regfeiva21['baseimp'] )); 
  }else{
    $regfeiva[]= array ( 'Id' => $regfeiva21['id'], 
                                'BaseImp' => $regfeiva21['importe'], 
                                'Importe' => $regfeiva21['baseimp'] );
   } }
    if ($regfeiva27["importe"]>0){

        if (count($regfeiva)>0){
          array_push($regfeiva,array ( 'Id' => $regfeiva27['id'], 
                                'BaseImp' => $regfeiva27['baseimp'], 
                                'Importe' => $regfeiva27['importe'] ));
        }else{
    $regfeiva[]=  array ( 'Id' => $regfeiva27['id'], 
                                'BaseImp' => $regfeiva27['baseimp'], 
                                'Importe' => $regfeiva27['importe'] );
   } }
```

Como trabajo con Jquery recibo las 3 alicuotas y su importe via AJAX, entonces mediante un condicional quiero cargarlo solo si el importe es mayor a 0, y si el array ay tiene de una alicuota concatenar pero no lo hace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para insertar elementos a un array ya definido en php, se puede hacer fácilmente de la siguiente forma `$var[] = elemento;` en casi todos los casos.

Mira este ejemplo:

```
<?php
$array1 = array(1);
$array1[] = 2;
print_r($array1); // array(1, 2)
$array1[] = array(7, 8);
$array1[] = array('a'=>'verde');
print_r($array1); // array(1, 2, array(7, 8), array('a'=>'verde'))
$array1[2][] = 9;
$array1[3]['b'] = 'azul';
print_r($array1); // array(1, 2, array(7, 8, 9), array('a'=>'verde', 'b'=>'azul'))

echo PHP_EOL;

$array2 = array('a'=>1);
$array2['b'] = 'hola';
print_r($array2); // array('a'=>1, 'b'=>hola)
$array2['c'] = array(1, 2);
print_r($array2); // array('a'=>1, 'b'=>hola, 'c'=>array(1, 2))
$array2['c'][] = 3;
print_r($array2); // array('a'=>1, 'b'=> hola, 'c'=>array(1, 2, 3))
```

Si tu lógica está correcta, entonces para añadir un elemento más al array, solo hay que asignarselo al array origen. Siendo eso así, ya no sería necesario el `if-else` más interno, porque serían exactamente iguales. Otra cosa, es que si es "bidimensional", entonces `$regfeiva` ya debe estar inicializado como *array*

```
<?php
$regfeiva = array(); // Inicializar $regfeiva
if ($regfeiva10["importe"]>0){
    $regfeiva[] = array('Id' => $regfeiva10['id'], 
    'BaseImp' => $regfeiva10['baseimp'], 
    'Importe' => $regfeiva10['importe'] );
}

if ($regfeiva21["importe"]>0){
    $regfeiva[] = array ( 'Id' => $regfeiva21['id'], 
    'BaseImp' => $regfeiva21['importe'], 
    'Importe' => $regfeiva21['baseimp'] );
}

if ($regfeiva27["importe"]>0){
    $regfeiva[] =  array( 'Id' => $regfeiva27['id'], 
    'BaseImp' => $regfeiva27['baseimp'], 
    'Importe' => $regfeiva27['importe'] );
}
```

Comment: Se hizo una modificación en la inicialización de $regfeiva (al principio) para que al aceptar los otros parametros sea bidimensional.

Comment: Gracias amigo! Me sirvio